# Any more 'daughters of God'?

Tags: midrash, historical-figures, pentateuch-chumash

As far as I have been able to ascertain, there were only two individuals explicitly referred to as a "daughter of God" or had God refer to them as "My daughter":

- Batya/Bithiah the daughter of Pharaoh, who adopted Moses (*Vayikra Rabba* 1:3)
- Osnat, the wife of Joseph (the Hellenistic text *Joseph and Asenath* 11).

In addition, the Torah itself was personalized and considered to be God's daughter in *Vayikra Rabba* 20.

Is anyone aware of anyone else so mentioned in Jewish literature, from earlier than the period of the Rishonim?

And is it significant that both of the women cited above were Egyptian? (I'm aware that there is an opinion that Osnat was a granddaughter of Yaakov [Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer 35, 37])